# How to know the group number from the ionization energy?

Tags: periodic-trends, periodic-table, ionization-energy

> The successive ionization energy of the first four electrons of a representative element are $\pu{738.1 kJ/mol}$, $\pu{1450 kJ/mol}$, $\pu{7730 kJ/mol}$ and $\pu{10500 kJ/mol}$. Characterize the element according to the periodic group.

From this data [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionization_energies_of_the_elements_(data_page)), I predicted that the element is $\ce{Mg}$ which belongs to Group 2. But I don't have a systematic way to predict the group number or the electron configuration from the question. Is there any approach for this kind of question ?

Comment: (1) Note that units like kJ/mol should be written in upright, not italics. It's not correct to simply place them in math mode `$...$` without anything else; either use `$1000~\mathrm{kJ/mol}$`, or perhaps more conveniently, `$\pu{1000 kJ/mol}$`. See https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/86/16683, especially section 3.3, for more info. (2) When copy-pasting links from Wikipedia, please try to edit out the links to the mobile version, this is not good for people using it on a desktop. You can do this by changing `en.m.wikipedia.org` to `en.wikipedia.org`.

Comment: Another way is using the [Wikipedia Android application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.wikipedia), (guessing iPhones have one too), which provides desktop links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The particular values are not that important. Their pattern is. Notice the big relative step between the 2nd and the 3rd ionization energies.

The first two values are relatively small as these electrons are quite shielded by more inner electrons.

The other two need much more energy to be taken away, being shielded much less, as the  "peer electrons" from the same orbital group do not shield the nucleus charge much for each other.

That means the first two electrons have started another element period with another quantum number $n$.
So the element group is the second group.